# sublime2 symbol definition howto

Tags: sublimetext2

I've switched to sublime2 a couple of months ago and I absolute love it!.

I'm just wondering if there could be a way to add symbol definitions to be recognized when triggering Ctrl+R shorcut.

I'm a Groovy/Grails programmer and we have closures as first level members in controllers (yep, wasn't able to switch to Grails 2.X at work yet).
When triggering Goto Symbol function I don't have the choice to navigate through my action definitions (closures).

It seems it's just looking for "**[modifier] returnType name([someArgs]) {}**" syntax and I guess it would be pretty easy to add some rule to identify "**def actionName = {}**" but I've been unable to find any file to add this "feature".

Is this possible?. If so, which file do I have to modify?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Groovy programmer. However, I took sample code from the official Groovy site and added closures to it to test my solution. It seems to work!

Briefly:

- Go into the Sublime menu, then select "Browse Packages..."
- Open the "Groovy" directory
- Edit the "Groovy.tmLanguage" file in Sublime

Go to line 860. It should read `(?=\() # opening parens`. Replace that line with the following lines:

```
(?=
    (?:\() # opening parens 
    |
    (?:=\s*\{) # or closure
)
```

Then, save the "Groovy.tmLanguage" file; Sublime should reload it instantly. You're done!

I recommend having a Groovy source code file open at the same time as you're editing the language definition -- you should see the syntax coloring kick in for closures right away. They will also now appear when triggering the "Goto Symbol" function.

Let me know if the new regular expression above messes up anything! :-) Cheers

Comment: I tried your solution and it actually works; by now nothing seems broken with that change so thank you very much Greg!. Such a pity I'm now in a python project and cannot benefit from this change.